# How can i make my new bullet points display a string?

Tags: javascript, html

First time posting, sorry if i do something wrong.

When i try to make a new list with js, the list elements only display [object HTMLLIElement] in the DOM. I would want it to make a new bullet point which says "Hello" each time i press the button.
It only shows this https://gyazo.com/f441c11ce81d80ff14ba4e207c1a7e2d

Here's my code.

```js
var bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
var ulist = document.createElement("ul");
var bulletpointEl = document.createElement("li");

bulletpointEl.innerHTML = "hello"
bodyEl.appendChild(ulist);

function bulletpoint() {
  ulist.innerHTML += bulletpointEl;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="bulletpoint()">New bulletpoint</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use *appendChild* instead of *innerHTML*. To create new *li* element in each button click, you have to create that inside the function.

I will also suggest you to use *textContent* instead of *innerHTML* when the content is simple text.

```js
var bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
var ulist = document.createElement("ul");

function bulletpoint(){
  var bulletpointEl = document.createElement("li");
  bulletpointEl.textContent = "hello"
  ulist.appendChild(bulletpointEl);
  bodyEl.appendChild(ulist);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="bulletpoint()">New bulletpoint</button>
<a href="../index.html">back</a>
```

Comment: The reason that `innerHTML` is often used instead of `textContent` is that up until a few years ago, `innerHTML` was supported by all browsers, while for text content you had to do browsersniffing and use `textContent` or `innerText`, depending.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to give innerHTML an object instead of a string.
innerHTML accepts a string - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Syntax

If you want to append an html element to the ulist you'll need to use the .appendChild() method same as you did with the bodyEl -

```
function bulletpoint(){
  ulist.appendChild(bulletpointEl);
}
```

Hope this helps!